# Parsing error: The keyword 'enum' is reserved

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, typescript-eslint

I am writing TypeScript with React. The project was generated with CRA. and I used `react-app` config for the `.eslintrc.json`. However I decided to use `eslint-config-airbnb` so I added it and changed my `.eslintrc.json`

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
  ]
}
```

suddenly I got parsing error from ESLint about the `enum` type I used in the codebase

```
`Parsing error: The keyword 'enum' is reserved eslint`
```

I googled it but cannot find the answer. Tried to add some extra config like

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 7,
  }
```

but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: is the word enum in your code base? Seems like you are using in way that does not define an enum.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out I just needed to add this one line in the config file of ESLint

```
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the getting started docs here for information on how to setup your typescript codebase for linting with ESLint.

This will run through all the steps to properly setup your codebase.

https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started/

You can just add the one line `"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"` to set the parser - but I'd still recommend reading the docs so you don't get into a weird state!